# jq using contains method when text value has quote literal

Tags: jq

I'm trying to use jq to filter my results when the value contains quote literals so my data looks like:

```
{"key": "site=\"abc\""}
```

I want to filter using contains (or some other method) for where site=abc but not site=abc123

current code that gets abc and abc123:

```
jq -c '.textPayload | select(contains("abc"))' test.json
```

I attempted to try to escape using \ but it looks like it doesn't work in the contains method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
$ echo '{"key": "site=\"abc\""}' | jq 'select(.key | contains("\"abc\""))'
{
  "key": "site=\"abc\""
}

$ echo '{"key": "site=\"abc\""}' | jq 'select(.key | index("\"abc\""))'
{
  "key": "site=\"abc\""
}

$ echo '{"key": "site=\"abc\""}' | jq 'select(.key | test("\"abc\""))'
{
  "key": "site=\"abc\""
}
```

So it's unclear what the difficulty is.